# How do I disable intelligent indentation in HTML files?

Tags: indentation

I've created a blank `example.html` file and I open it in Vim, and I add the following contents:

```
<div>
```

Still in insert mode, at the end of the line, if I press <kbd>enter</kbd>, the new line will automatically be indented for when I type `<p>`:

```
<div>
        <p>
```

Clearly, something knows that `<div>` expects children, which should be indented, and is indenting the following line automatically for me. What is enabling this? How do I disable this, without disabling other automatic indentation features like `:set autoindent copyindent`?

Note that `:set smartindent?` displays `nosmartindent`, so it's not that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that Vim ships with a bunch of `indent.vim` files (enabled with `:filetype indent on`), including one for HTML. You can read help for it at `:help html-indenting`.

This HTML indent file sets `indentexpr` option to a function that knows how to parse HTML. When `indentexpr` is set, it overrules `cindent` and `smartindent`. If you want to disable it, run `:set indentexpr=`.

If you want to always disable it, put this in your `.vimrc` file:

```
au FileType html,htmldjango setlocal indentexpr=
```

Comment: You might instead `setlocal indentkeys=` That way you can still use `=` to indent lines on demand if you wish.

Comment: @Antony Fascinating! I didn't know about the `=` key until now! (`:help =`)

Comment: @Antony Hi, could you maybe clarify what you mean? Thanks!